# Two ways of solving the second derivative

Tags: derivatives, chain-rule

Here is the situation: say $f(u)=y=u^2$, and $g(x)=u=x^2$ and we want to find $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$.

I have two ways of solving this:

1. Substituting $u=x^2$ and writing $y$ as,
   $$y=(x^2)^2=x^4$$
   $$\frac{dy}{dx}=4x^3 \implies\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=12x^2 $$

Or

2. Straight away differentiating $y$ with respect to $x$
   $$\frac{dy}{dx}=2u\frac{du}{dx} \implies\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=2\left[u\frac{d^2u}{dx^2}+\frac{du}{dx}\left(\frac{du}{dx}\right)\right]\text{[Using Chain rule]}$$

\begin{align}
\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} & = 2\left[u\frac{d^2u}{dx^2}+\frac{du}{dx}\left(\frac{du}{dx}\right)\right] \\
 & = 2\left[x^2(2)+2x(2x)\right]\\
&= 2[2x^2+4x^2]\\
&=2[6x^2]\\
&=12x^2
\end{align}

Are both of these ways correct to solve this question?

Comment: I think you mean the product rule right? And not the chain rule. Of course you use the chain rule in other places. Finally, you have two different ways of solving the same problem which give you the same answer, where you have a justification for each step. Why do you think you did something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, both methods used for finding the second derivative $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$ are correct and lead to the same result.

The **first method** is a straightforward application of the power rule. It substitutes $u$ with $x^2$ directly in $y$, and then takes the derivative with respect to $x$.

The **second method** applies the chain rule for differentiation. It first finds the derivative of $y$ with respect to $u$ and then multiplies it by the derivative of $u$ with respect to $x$.

Both approaches works here, leading to the same result $12x^2$ you found.

Hope this helps!